# Stereovslam error :: Assertion `left_.tfFrame() == right_.tfFrame()'

Tags: ros, vslam-system, image-geometry, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After i publish my two left and right videos from stereo camera and run stereo_synchronizer node and stereo_image_proc node everything seems to go file but i get this error from stereo_vslam_node and see no output:

stereo_vslam_node: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_opencv/image_geometry/src/stereo_camera_model.cpp:28: bool image_geometry::StereoCameraModel::fromCameraInfo(const sensor_msgs::CameraInfo&, const sensor_msgs::CameraInfo&): Assertion `left_.tfFrame() == right_.tfFrame()' failed.

[image: image description]
You can zoom in the file by opening it in another window.
Here is how my system looks , does anybody has anyidea what might be going wrong ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10376/stereovslam-error-::-assertion-%60left_.tfframe()-==-right_.tfframe()%27/) by [rajat](https://answers.ros.org/users/591/rajat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 175 on 2011-06-23

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the frame on each camera should be the same. You're likely using separate frames for each, which might make intuitive sense, but the transforms re camerainfo are all meant to be referencing the same frame, and so stereo_image_proc needs them to be the same.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2